Connecting VSCode and SQL Developer from Host Machine to Oracle DB 19c on Hyper-V virtual machine
I cannot connect SQL Developer or VSCode from Host machine to Oracle 19c DB hosted on the Virtual Machine.
SQL Developer Error Below:
An error was encountered performing the requested operation: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=jaboSwmfSBiYukjDv3hEsg==) Vendor code 17002
VSCode Error Below:
Error: A connection with the database could not be established
Source: Oracle SQL Developer Extension for VSCode
Environment Setup:
Host Machine: Installed: Windows 11 Pro
Installed VSCode
Installed Oracle client for Microsoft Tools
Configured Path instantclient_19_24
Hyper V: Virtual Machine installed Windows Server 2016
Only one netwok adapter available which is inbulit in laptop -> Virtual Machine and Host Machine use the same network adapter.
Oracle Listener Status Below:
command lineC:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl status
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 19-AUG-2024 13:18:33
Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=VMWIN2016SER)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                19-AUG-2024 11:35:09
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 43 min. 24 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\db_home\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oracle19c_agcadmin\diag\tnslsnr\VMWIN2016SER\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=VMWIN2016SER)(PORT=1521)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=VMWIN2016SER)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\ORACLE19C_AGCADMIN\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0.agc.local" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "66d05b08751d4f5399f9cf1e3e332e21.agc.local" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl.agc.local" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.agc.local" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclpdb.agc.local" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
I have successfully connected SQL Developer & VSCode to Oracle 19c DB on the Virtual Machine.But Cannot connect from my Host machine.

the easiest thing to do is create a local port forward that does traffic on 1521 to and from your host and vm - so you can connect to the database on localhost:1521, vs guessing what the addressable IP is from host

Dear @thatjeffsmith can you show me on how to do it on windows machine?

Go-to your VM network settings and port forward 1521 from host to client, I can show you on virtualbox?
